# Selecting column based on date of another column in a query

Tags: sqlite

I have several unrelated tables that ive been trying to join together, and my problem comes from one column grabbing the first result, which produces inaccurate data. This was augmented with a date field, but i cannot get it to produce the results desired.

table a:

| locations | companies | dates |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 321 | 111 | 1/1 |
| 123 | 222 | 2/2 |
| 321 | 222 | 3/3 |
| 123 | 111 | 4/4 |

table b:

| job | locations |
| --- | --- |
| zzz | 321 |
| xxx | 123 |

```
select a.companies, b.locations, b.job
where a.locations=b.locations
group by b.job
```

There have been other attempts, but all of these return invalid results. I even tried a case a.companies > 1, and doing a sub-query off that. I might have just hit my limit being a noob at this.

Is there a way for a.companies to return the result of the latest date in a.dates?

End result should look like:

| companies | locations | job |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 222 | 321 | zzz |
| 111 | 123 | xxx |

Instead, it is grabbing the 1st result found in a.companies (as its the first result):

| companies | locations | job |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | 321 | zzz |
| 222 | 123 | xxx |

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my problem by using ROW_NUMBER(), and joining on the row number on what was table a. This question can be closed. The end query looked like:

```
SELECT location, company
from (select
a.location,
b.company,
a.date,
row_number() over(partition by a.location order by a.date DESC) rn
where a.job=b.job
group by a.location, b.company, a.date
order by b.company, a.date DESC) t
where t.rn = 1
group by company, location
order by company;
```

Comment: even allowing for the plurals being turned into singulars, your table b has no company column, and none of your selects specify any from clause

Comment: You're correct. I was sleep deprived through this entire process, and i couldnt share the entire problem and dataset. 

However, i was able to solve my problem using a query similar to the one above.